# Creating/downloading an excel file with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, excel, google-chrome-extension, download, xlsx

I've been basically trying to make a chrome extension that dynamically creates an xlsx file and then downloads it. I believe I can use [chrome.downloads](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) to download the file, but I'm not sure how to dynamically create the xlsx file.

I wanted to use the [exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs) module but I don't know if it only works on Node. Is there any other way to create an xlsx file with a chrome extension?

Comment: Assuming you don't need any special formatting, have you considered saving your spreadsheet in `CSV` format?  Excel will be able to open this extension and might well be the default application for it.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be a formatted xls file :/

Answer (score 1):

`SheetJS` looks like a popular client-side solution. https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: I took a look at that, but it doesn't seem to work with Browserify.