# Is it possible to write data from a chrome extension to a local excel sheet?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created a chrome extension that take some user data and automate some tasks in a certain website, i have read that chrome extensions have no access to local files and i need to write the user data to an excel sheet. i don't know if that has changed lately!

Is that possible to automatically send data after user interaction with the extension to a local excel sheet?

Comment: You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282228/creating-downloading-an-excel-file-with-a-chrome-extension) + the new [FileSystem](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) API.

Comment: I know that stackoverflow community is against thanking people, but man,  really thank you you saved my day many times, and if you want, you can add this comment as an answer and i will accept it